# GTKでTextViewウィジェットの全体の背景を変える

Tags: c, gtk, gui

GTK+でTextViewのウェジット全体の背景を
最新のバージョンで変えられるものはありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 概要

Gtk3 ではウィジェットの外観を CSS で設定出来ます。
これは HTML で行なわれている事と同じ考え方です。
ただし、CSS などの仕様に厳密に従っているわけではありません。
リファレンスの関連箇所は [Part IV. Theming in GTK+](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/theming.html) です。

CSSの概要は [Overview of CSS in GTK+](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html)で、サポートされている CSS プロパティは [Supported CSS Properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-properties.html) で説明されています。

### 流れ

まずは変更したいウィジェットの CSS ノードを確認します。
[GtkTextView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html#GtkTextView.description) は下記のノードを持ちます。

```
CSS nodes

textview.view
├── border.top
├── border.left
├── text
│   ╰── [selection]
├── border.right
├── border.bottom
╰── [window.popup]
```

これを見て、CSS のセレクタを決めます。
通常のテキスト部分は `textview.view text` で、選択中のテキスト部分は `textview.view text selection` かな、などとあたりを付けておいて、試行する事になります。

そのセレクタにスタイルを当てるのですが、背景色を変更するならば、前景色（文字などの色）やカーソルの色なども同時に指定する必要があります。
ユーザーがどのようなテーマを使用しているか分からないからです。
背景色だけ指定すると、その色がユーザーが使用している前景色と近く、文字などが読めなくなる可能性があります。

```css
textview.view text {
    color: white;
    caret-color: green;
    background-color: black;
}
textview.view text selection {
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

作ったCSS は [GtkCssProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html) にロードします。
その GtkCssProvider を何らかの [GtkStyleContext](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html) に追加する事で外観が変わります。
スタイルをアプリケーション全体に適用するならば、"screen" に対して [`gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-style-context-add-provider-for-screen) で追加します。
特定のウィジェットに適用するならば、そのウィジェットから [`gtk_widget_get_style_context()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-style-context) で取得した GtkStyleContext に [`gtk_style_context_add_provider()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-style-context-add-provider) で追加します。

### 例

Python になりますがスタイルの設定を数パターン使用している例です。

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import gi
gi.require_version('GLib', '2.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Gtk

# イベントループ
loop = GLib.MainLoop()

# メインウィンドウ
win = Gtk.Window.new(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
win.set_title("スタイル変更")
win.connect("delete-event", lambda *x: loop.quit())

# コンテナ
box = Gtk.VBox.new(True, 10)
win.add(box)

# バッファ
buf = Gtk.TextBuffer.new(None)
buf.set_text("今日は、世界！\n Hello, world!\n")

# ビュー
view_01 = Gtk.TextView.new_with_buffer(buf)
view_01.set_name("top")
box.add(view_01)

view_02 = Gtk.TextView.new_with_buffer(buf)
box.add(view_02)

view_03 = Gtk.TextView.new_with_buffer(buf)
box.add(view_03)

# テキストビューの背景を黒くする CSS
# top と名付けたテキストビューには個別のスタイルを指定
# デフォルトのフォントは text ノードではなくテキストビューのトップレベルに指定する模様
black_css = Gtk.CssProvider.new()
black_css.load_from_data(
    b"""
textview.view text {
    color: white;
    caret-color: green;
    background-color: black;
}
textview.view text selection {
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}

textview.view#top text {
    color: orange;
}
textview.view#top {
    font: 1.5em serif;
}
    """)

# 上の CSS を全体に設定
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
    win.get_property("screen"),
    black_css,
    Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
)

# 背景を灰色にする CSS
gray_css = Gtk.CssProvider.new()
gray_css.load_from_data(
    b"""
textview.view text {
    background-color: gray;
}
    """)

# 上の CSS をテキストビュー 02 に設定
style_context = view_02.get_style_context();
style_context.add_provider(gray_css, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)


# スタート
win.show_all()
loop.run()
```

[image: スタイル変更の例]